# Cant acces from host to cloudera WEBHDFS (Guest)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, webhdfs

I have read about Web Hdfs in all this links

[link1](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Open_and_Read_a_File)  [link2](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/manager/5-1-x/Cloudera-Manager-Managing-Clusters/cm5mc_hdfs_enable_webhdfs.html) [link3](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)

checking with telnet - the port is OPEN

made the needed settings in cloudera ( virtual box) to make webhdfs enable
testing directly on cloudera works:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ curl -i -L "http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN"
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
http://quickstart.cloudera:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=quickstart.cloudera:8020&offset=0
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 14:08:07 GMT
Date: Tue, 01 Dec 2015 14:08:07 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
```

trying directly on cloudera web browser also work for :

```
http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN
```

I am able to send PING `C:\Users\User>ping 10.0.0.88`

Telnet working for port 50070.

But when trying this command outside the cluster it dosnt work (HOST)

```
"http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN"
```

more info
LISTSTATUS works from HOST

```
http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFileop=LISTSTATUS&user.name=hadoop`
```

returns

```
  {"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[
    {"accessTime":1448982310759,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":26625,"group":"cloudera","length":47,"modificationTime":1448978300739,"owner":"cloudera","pathSuffix":"","permission":"644","replication":1,"type":"FILE"}
    ]}}
```

but op=OPEN  from HOST

```
"http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN&user.name=hadoop"
```

returns

```
This webpage is not available
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is syntax problem in

```
http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?`op=OPEN&user.name=hadoop`
```

Try

```
http://10.0.0.88:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/cloudera/testdir/testFile?op=OPEN
```

Comment: tried that not the reason - getting same error 
its seems i have a problem with op=OPEN - what could be the problem ?